# TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out (Python socket request)

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

I am fairly new to Python (just started today) but am really struggling with this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import socket

s=socket.socket()
s.connect(("<my ip addres>", 22))

answer=s.recv(1024)
print(answer)

s.close
```

I believe I am meant to be getting some sort of 'banner' response but it gives nothing for a few minutes before spouting the following error:
**TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out**

Why would this be happening?

Comment: The server does not want to respond.

Comment: This is not something related to the code, its really just that your computer(or a website) did not respond. Maybe you lost wifi

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you connect to port 22. Then make sure your operating system's firewall doesn't block incoming connections to port 22. In case the address you have configured for the server is "localhost" and try to connect from another machine you won't be able to connect. In that case you shoud use "" as ip address.